# AJAX Validation, ajax not execute but it send get to index.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

So I was looking how to validate before AJAX executes. My AJAX was works fine before I add `if ($("#ModalsForm").validate()){}`. After I add that validate, it will validate and return true and send Get to my index.php.

```
index.php?bookingid=10040917035610&roomid=10&...
```

My HTML

```
<form id="ModalsForm" method="post" data-parsley-excluded="[disabled=disabled]">
     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" 
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none;">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modalcontent">
            <!-- AJAX onclick content modal -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
         </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div>
 </form>
```

My AJAX

```js
function ConfirmSubmit() {
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to save or update?");
  if (x) {
    if ($("#ModalsForm").validate()) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/BookingCalendar/runsave.php",
        data: $("#ModalsForm").serialize(),
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
          //$("#information").html(result);
          $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
        }
      });
      return false;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Did I miss something when I validate my form?

```
<script>
$('#ModalsForm').validate({
  submitHandler: function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save or update?")) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/BookingCalendar/runsave.php",
        data: $("#ModalsForm").serialize(),
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function (result) {
          alert(result);
          $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); 
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Newest From Rory McCrossan, it's caught error in console

Comment: `e.preventDefault()`: `e` is not defined anywhere. Did you check the console for errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery validate and want to submit the form via AJAX you should invert the logic, so that you use the `submitHandler` option of the plugin to implement your own logic when the form is valid, like this:

```
$('#ModalsForm').validate({
  rules: { /* your rules. .*/ },
  messages: { /* your messages... */ },
  submitHandler: function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save or update?")) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/BookingCalendar/runsave.php",
        data: $("#ModalsForm").serialize(),
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function (result) {
          $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); 
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

You can then remove the `ConfirmSubmit()` function, and just submit the `form` element normally.

Comment: so required inside input is useless when i use ajax ?

Comment: No, you can still use that method too, this was just for an example

Comment: hm.. validation is work, but my ajax not even working after i try to use 
submitHandler: function() {} and it submit just like there is no script i think

Comment: Apologies - I missed the `return false;`. I updated the answer for you

Comment: wait i will update my code, because it's skip the script

Comment: IT'S WORK ty
after i change my script place the console showing
.validate is not function
and i add
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> and it's work ty